# How to make a frosted glass effect in photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects

Wondering how to make effect like the picture below? looks like frosted glass, 
i guess it was made by photoshop effect or realistic photo. Does anyone know how to make this kind of effect ? Thanks:)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That is a real photo. Based on the ideas by Karl Gerstner in "Programme as grid". Very good design book [Designing Programmes](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3037780932), worth the read.

"Frosted glass" effect is usually used in reference to "blurred" picture. The effect on the poster is classified, in photoshop, as "blocks" (or Wire Mesh Security Glass IRL).

You can find this filter in Filters>filter gallery>distort>glass and in Photoshop versions before CS6 in Filter>distort>glass

You may find you need to use this filter separately on layers with different shapes and colors to achieve the same color change.